# For Google Analytics, is or is not urchin.js still working properly

Tags: google-analytics

(Re that "What's your programming question?", I would not call this a programming question, but https://developers.google.com/analytics/community/ directed me here, so fingers crossed.)

My page www.chrisjj.com is using urchinTracker:

```
<script src="http://www.google-analytics.com/urchin.js" 
type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
_uacct = "UA-1659403-1";
urchinTracker();
</script>
```

but I see reports on web e.g. [here](https://www.morevisibility.com/blogs/analytics/say-goodbye-to-three-old-friends-urchintracker-pagetracker-and-gaq-push.html) that "Google will officially deprecate Urchin.js and sites that fail to upgrade *will no longer have their data processed*."

I'm seeing some data in my GA reports, but... it is complete? I.e. is urchin.js still working properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Google](https://analytics.googleblog.com/2009/04/urchinjs-is-going-dark-no-it-isnt.html):

```
...there is no immediate need or requirement to do so.
```

Benefits (upgrading to ga.js, even that is out of date now):

- Faster, smaller source file
- Automatic detection of HTTPS
- Increased namespace safety
- More convenient set up for tracking e-commerce transactions
- More customizable code for interactive Ajax-based sites
- Ability to take advantage of the most up-to-date tracking
  functionality as it is added to Google Analytics

If you're just using the basics, I think it is very easy to upgrade to the latest implementation method and worth looking into.

Comment: "there is no immediate need or requirement to do so"... in 2009! So it would still be nice to have an answer to the question. E.g. from any expert user of urchin.js who has found it is working properly for him/her.

Comment: It won't be accurate for all the reports but will be accurate for pageviews if that's all you're after. I had a look at your site and it is simple enough to upgrade.

Comment: "It won't be accurate for all the reports". OK, so that's /not/ working properly, then. Thanks. I'll look into the upgrade... wondering how long it will be before that goes wrong too :)